# Будет ли утечка памяти при таком конструкторе?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, имеется 2 класса:

```
   public class FIO
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Fam;
     [XmlAttribute]
    public int Otch;
}

[XmlRoot]
public class Addr
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Street;
    [XmlElement]
    public int HouseNum;
    [XmlArray]
    public List<FIO> FIOs = new List<FIOs>();

    public Addr()
    {

    }

    public Addr(string filePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(GetType());
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var t = (Addr)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            Street = t.Street;
            HouseNum = t.HouseNum;
            FIOs = t.FIOs;
        }
    }
}
```

Переменная t из конструктора Addr будет собрана частично сборщиком мусора или нет(t.Street и t.HouseNum) или эти ненужны поля будут висеть в памяти, из-за

FIOs ?

Если да, то как можно организовать конструктор правильнее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, утечки памяти не будет.

Поле `HouseNum` будет скопировано (т. к. это тип-значение), остальные поля будут «украдены» у объекта `t` и присвоены текущему объекту. Поскольку у этих полей нету ссылки на `t`, то они не держат `t` в памяти, так что `t` вполне доступен для сбора сборщиком мусора.

---

Мне кажется, правильнее было бы не десериализировать другой объект, чтобы стащить у него поля, а сделать отдельный фабричный метод:

```
// сериализатор общий, так что не будем создавать его каждый раз
static XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Addr));
static public Addr DeserializeFromPath(string filePath)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        return (Addr)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

При этом необходимость в конструкторе десериализации отпадает.